# trim, trimming random char off

Tags: php, trim

Soo im building this project where i trim a string.
First i will show you the full string named channel:

```
 [2018-04-04 12:52:52] production.INFO: usercompany.login
```

then when i want to trim this string i use this:

```
 $trchannel = trim($channel, 'usercompany.'); 
 \Log::info($trchannel);
```

What i would expect = login.

What i get =

```
 [2018-04-04 12:53:32] production.INFO: logi
```

pls someone explain to me, how this could be possible????

Comment: $trchannel = str_replace('usercompany.', ' ', $channel); and do a dd($channel) before this to make sure $channel has the right string in it. And remove the laravel tag since this is related to php only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your example, this is the starting variable:

```
$channel = 'usercompany.login';
```

The end goal is:

```
$trchannel = 'login';
```

Trim is actually used for removing whitespace, not for replacing or substituting. The 2nd argument in the `trim` function is for a character mask.

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

What you could use instead is `str_replace`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

So an example:

```
$channel = 'usercompany.login';
$trchannel = str_replace('usercompany.', '', $channel);

// outputs 'login'
echo $trchannel;
```

`str_replace` takes the search criteria as first argument, then what to replace the found string with as the 2nd argument, finally it takes the actual string as the third argument.

Comment: Oh okee i didnt know that, but still dont understand why the 'n' from login gets cut off, it worked on usercompany.users just fine, only when i used usercompany.login it randomly cut off the 'n' char.

Comment: The `trim` function accepts a `character_mask` as a second argument, a `character_mask` is slightly different from your regular string. I have a feeling that something in "login" has a special trigger. `trim` is usually used for removing whitespaces or non standard characters, you'll run into some funky stuff if you try to use it for removing portions of strings.